# Mobile navigation with doubletaptogo automatically collapses first drop down

Tags: jquery, html, css

The mobile navigation on a site I am helping to make responsive is giving me some trouble.

[www.pioneerannouncements.com/test/](http://www.pioneerannouncements.com/test/)

it works in browser but not on mobile devices.

The drop downs work for "about us" and "dealers" but not for the first dropdown "invitations" it drops down then immediately pulls back up.

Im using doubletaptogo and trying to clean up a lot of old html and css on the site.

Cant seem to figure out the issue with this, don't know if another element is getting in the way or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about this [plugin](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly), you have to add this `JS file` below to your site, which you are not linking.

[JS File](http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/doubletaptogo.js)

See Documentation:

> Touch-friendly drop-down navigation
>
> Drop-Down Navigation: Responsive and Touch-FriendlyThe most important
>   things go in the end: let's finally solve the problem described in the
>   very first paragraphs of the post. Here comes the promised super
>   lightweight jQuery plugin which I called [DoubleTapToGo.js](http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/doubletaptogo.js) and it is
>   only 550 ridiculous bytes in size when [minified](http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/doubletaptogo.min.js).
>
> When you tap the parent item for the first time, DoubleTapToGo
>   prevents the browser from opening a new URL but allows that if tapped
>   once again in succession. If there is an intermediate tap(s) between
>   the first one and the second the counter resets. Quite simple
>   principle of operation, isn't it? It may be hard to believe but this
>   solved all of the flaws I have mentioned before.
>
> Considering the markup above, the plugin should be only applied to the
>   items that are parents – in order to avoid double-tap requirement on
>   drop-down-less items:
>
> `$( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();`

Comment: not found in your code, at least with this name. did you change it?

Comment: it is in js/doubletaptogo.js

did i call it correctly?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yywMOg.html

Comment: ahhh you are right, I included the min but only called the original

Comment: Thanks again! I can't believe how long I was working on this trying to get it to work and overlooked that.